# axiom of choice is equivalent to "the product of nonempty collection of nonempty sets is nonempty"

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Axiom of choice:\
If {$A_\alpha \vert \alpha \in A$ }  is an indexed family of nonempty pairwise-disjoint sets, there is a function $f$ from $A$  to $\cup A_\alpha  $ such that $f(\alpha )\in A_\alpha$, for each $\alpha \in A$
From this definition I need to obtain an equivanlence to the product of nonempty collection of nonempty sets is nonempty, but I have a problem in the part of pairwise disjoint sets. Help!

Comment: Replace $A_{\alpha}$ by $A_{\alpha}\times \{\alpha\}$

Comment: If product_k A_k is not empty.  Let product_k x_k be in the product.  Then k -> x_k in A_k is a needed choice function.

Comment: Conversely, if for all j, f(j) in A_j, then product_j f(j) in product_j A_j.